# Pandas Reading Websocket Data - Fyers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, websocket

I have the following websocket data which I am saving to a file.

```
def custom_message(msg):
        #print(msg)
        g=open('NSE_JSON.csv','a')
        g.write(f"{msg}")
        g.write("\n")
        g.close()
```

URL : [Pastebin Socket](https://pastebin.com/M9zv7Fyi)

```
[{'symbol': 'NSE:BANKNIFTY2351844500CE', 'timestamp': 1684132127, 'fyCode': 7208, 'fyFlag': 2, 'pktLen': 200, 'ltp': 68.45, 'open_price': 45.0, 'high_price': 74.7, 'low_price': 33.95, 'close_price': 46.6, 'min_open_price': 68.45, 'min_high_price': 68.6, 'min_low_price': 67.9, 'min_close_price': 68.45, 'min_volume': 32375, 'last_traded_qty': 25, 'last_traded_time': 1684132126, 'avg_trade_price': 5679, 'vol_traded_today': 22284200, 'tot_buy_qty': 451350, 'tot_sell_qty': 285300, 'market_pic': [{'price': 68.05, 'qty': 575, 'num_orders': 7}, {'price': 68.0, 'qty': 2550, 'num_orders': 20}, {'price': 67.95, 'qty': 1400, 'num_orders': 9}, {'price': 67.9, 'qty': 975, 'num_orders': 6}, {'price': 67.84, 'qty': 225, 'num_orders': 2}, {'price': 68.25, 'qty': 325, 'num_orders': 1}, {'price': 68.3, 'qty': 1350, 'num_orders': 7}, {'price': 68.34, 'qty': 225, 'num_orders': 1}, {'price': 68.4, 'qty': 750, 'num_orders': 4}, {'price': 68.45, 'qty': 1300, 'num_orders': 7}]}]
```

I want to get the timestamp,vol_traded_today values in a dataframe.

I have tried to use json_loads but not working as the data is not coming as json.

Thanks

Expecting a return dataframe

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(msg))`?

Answer (score 0):

If your sample is a list, you can use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(lst)[['symbol', 'timestamp', 'vol_traded_today']]
print(df)

# Output
                      symbol   timestamp  vol_traded_today
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351843000PE  1684132122          16217075
```

Update: use `ast.literal_eval` to transform plain text as python structure:

```
import ast

cols = ['symbol', 'timestamp', 'vol_traded_today']
data = []
with open('NSE_JSON.csv') as fp:
    for row in fp:
        df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(row))[cols]
        data.append(df)
df = pd.concat(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                      symbol   timestamp  vol_traded_today
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351843000PE  1684132122          16217075
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351844500CE  1684132122          22282750
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351843000PE  1684132123          16217875
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351844500CE  1684132123          22283025
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351843000PE  1684132124          16218400
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351844500CE  1684132124          22283125
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351843000PE  1684132125          16222525
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351844500CE  1684132125          22283825
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351843000PE  1684132126          16222525
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351844500CE  1684132126          22283875
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351843000PE  1684132127          16222525
0  NSE:BANKNIFTY2351844500CE  1684132127          22284200
```

Comment: Reading of the file would be like this ..
with open('NSE_JSON.csv') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

Comment: Getting Error..

saurabhgarg@Saurabhs-MacBook-Pro NSE_deployed % python3 delete_read_json.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saurabhgarg/shivshakti/fyersalgo/NSE_deployed/delete_read_json.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_data)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Comment: However, it would be better if you write a correct structure in your file when you receive new data.

Comment: Using AST its never completes and keep running as this file gets bigger with time.

Comment: The structure of the date i cant define , as its coming from broker. whatever is coming is i am writing in the file.

Comment: I want to read the data from the file in a dataframe. Resampling and sum i will do once the data is in dataframe.

Comment: So you want to read the file while the file is open and you're writing to it? :)

Comment: File is in closed state. 

As you suggested using json_normalize.Getting Error.

import pandas as pd
import json

#loading a json file

with open('NSE_JSON_1.csv') as f:
  d=json.load(f)

df=pd.json_normalize(d)
print(df.head())